# Corrupted Access Database

Tags: restore, ms-access, corruption

I have a big Access database, with aobout 150 Tables/Queries/Linked txt files/Macros/Modules.

I was working today, and then from out of nowhere the database got corrupted. I googled, and forund that exporting all the Objects into another database solves the Problem. I did that, and it worked on Objects and Queries, but Macros and Modules i can't Export... I alwasy get an error message: "id" is not an index in this table. And then Nothing happens. I also cant open the modules or the Visual Basic Editor. 
I tried the compact and repair tool, but It gives me the same error message multiple times. 
I tried to open the module in design mode, but get this error message "The module Name 'XY' is misspellen or refers to a module that does't exist.
Everything I tried doesn't seem to work… The Macros are not so important, but the modules where a lot of work to put together…

Does anyone have an idea how I can repair These modules?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No backup? **No mercy**! You tried everything from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871578/9439330?

Comment: Yes... I tried all the steps there. I only don't have any Access to my modules and macros

Comment: You tried import instead of export? Also you read [Access-Database-Corruption-Repair-Guide](https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Access-Database-Corruption-Repair-Guide)? If you can afford (company? or private?), they should be able to recover most  data.

Comment: I tried both, but could only save tables and queries

Comment: Did you send the db to https://www.everythingaccess.com/upload?reference=ARX-1645894482&allowcomments=1 to get a free recovery report? For help from me, you need to add a list of what you've done and what happens then to your question, or maybe upload db (zip it!) to a fileshare (only if data is not sensitive and this is no company db (except  charity)), so we can try ourself

Comment: Thanks for your help @ComputerVersteher. I had a couple week old Version of my database. There I had a Little bit of my modules and macros. I was able to recreate the database VBA and macros in a whole days work. Thanks anyway. Have a nice day

Comment: And yes. Now I make a backup of my database every day. (Should have started like that :))

Comment: Glad to hear that mate! I hope you chosed a proper backup strategy (regular backups, indiependent hardware, regular restore test). A backup on the same machine and hdd is almost useless. And RAID is not a backup!

Comment: My backups lies on an the Companies online Server which is also backed up daily. I hope thats good enough :) Thanks again!!

Comment: Ever tested a restore? One thing I totally forgot was volume shadow copies. Maybe they are turned on and you can restore a previous version of the db file.